# Custom division of axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replace the ticks on the x axis with a custom indicator of the length between some points. Something like this:

[image: Sample]

So far I have been able to do everything except replace the ticks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
    title = {Ekick Electrode Voltage},
    axis lines = middle,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    ymin = -80,
    ymax = -17,
    ylabel = {Voltage~[V]},
    xmajorticks=false
    ]
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=0:10e-9, samples=100]  {(43) * pow(1 + exp(-(x - 10e-9 / 2) * 4.5 * 2 / 10e-9), -1) - 70};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=10e-9:30e-9, samples=100]  {-27};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=40e-9:45e-9, samples=100, ->]  {-70};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=30e-9:40e-9, samples=100]  {(-43) * pow(1 + exp(-((x - 30e-9) - 10e-9 / 2) * 4.5 * 2 / 10e-9), -1) - 27};
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=50] coordinates {(10e-9,-85)(10e-9,-20)};
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=50] coordinates {(30e-9,-85)(30e-9,-20)};
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=50] coordinates {(40e-9,-85)(40e-9,-20)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Can someone point me into how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the vertical dashed plots also to define symbolic coordinates that can be used for annotations outside the axis environment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title = {Ekick Electrode Voltage},
    axis lines = middle,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    ymin = -80,
    ymax = -17,
    ylabel = {Voltage~[V]},
    xmajorticks=false
    ]
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=0:10e-9, samples=100]  {(43) * pow(1 + exp(-(x - 10e-9 / 2) * 4.5 * 2 / 10e-9), -1) - 70};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=10e-9:30e-9, samples=100]  {-27};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=40e-9:45e-9, samples=100, ->]  {-70};
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=30e-9:40e-9, samples=100]  {(-43) * pow(1 + exp(-((x - 30e-9) - 10e-9 / 2) * 4.5 * 2 / 10e-9), -1) - 27};
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(10e-9,-85)(10e-9,-20)}
        coordinate (p1);
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(30e-9,-85)(30e-9,-20)}
        coordinate (p2);
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(40e-9,-85)(40e-9,-20)}
        coordinate (p3);
    \path (0,0) coordinate (p0);    
 \end{axis}
 \path ([yshift=-1em]current axis.south) coordinate (l);
 \begin{scope}[>=latex,<->,shorten >=0.2pt,shorten <=0.2pt,
    nodes={text height=1.4ex}]
  \draw (p0|-l) -- (p1|-l) node[midway,below]{$10\,$ms};
  \draw (p1|-l) -- (p2|-l) node[midway,below]{Delay Time};
  \draw (p2|-l) -- (p3|-l) node[midway,below]{$10\,$ms};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think one needs to fix the blue plot as well. This can be done by drawing one plot and using `tanh` for the smoothening of the steps.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title = {Ekick Electrode Voltage},
    axis lines = middle,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    ymin = -80,
    ymax = -17,
    ylabel = {Voltage~[V]},
    xmajorticks=false,
    declare function={x1=10e-9;x2=30e-9;x3=40e-9;x4=45e-9;y1=-70;y2=-27;}
    ]
    \addplot[thick, blue, domain=0:x4, samples=101,-stealth]  
    {y1+ (y2-y1)*(1/2+tanh(6*(x-x1/2)/x1)/2) 
       + (y1-y2)*(1/2+tanh(6*(x-x2/2-x3/2)/x1)/2)};
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(x1,-85)(x1,-20)}
        coordinate (p1);
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(x2,-85)(x2,-20)}
        coordinate (p2);
    \addplot[thick, dashed, samples=2] coordinates {(x3,-85)(x3,-20)}
        coordinate (p3);
    \path (0,0) coordinate (p0);    
 \end{axis}
 \path ([yshift=-1em]current axis.south) coordinate (l);
 \begin{scope}[>=latex,<->,shorten >=0.2pt,shorten <=0.2pt,
    nodes={text height=1.4ex}]
  \draw (p0|-l) -- (p1|-l) node[midway,below]{$10\,$ms};
  \draw (p1|-l) -- (p2|-l) node[midway,below]{Delay Time};
  \draw (p2|-l) -- (p3|-l) node[midway,below]{$10\,$ms};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]